# Regular expression to find syllables in Bengali word

Tags: python, regex, unicode, nlp

Here is the code:

```
BanglaAlphabet = {
    'Consonant'                   : '[\u0995-\u09B9\u09CE\u09DC-\u09DF]',
    'IndependantVowel'            : '[\u0985-\u0994]',
    'DependantVowel'              : '[\u09BE-\u09CC\u09D7]',
    'Nukta'                       : '[\u09BC]'
}
BanglaWordPattern = ur"""(
    ({DependantVowel}{Nukta}{Consonant}) |
    ({DependantVowel}{Consonant}) |
    {IndependantVowel} |
    {Consonant} |
)+""".format(**BanglaAlphabet)
BanglaWordPattern = re.compile(BanglaWordPattern, re.VERBOSE)
```

The matching is done with:

```
re.match(BanglaWordPattern, w[::-1])
```

This is meant to match a valid Bengali word when matched from right to left.

However, it is matching invalid words, such as োগাড় and িদগ.

What could be the problem?

#### Edit

After numerous corrections as suggested by @GarethRees and @ChrisMorgan, I ended up with:

```
bangla_alphabet = dict(
    consonant         = u'[\u0995-\u09b9\u09ce\u09dc-\u09df]',
    independent_vowel = u'[\u0985-\u0994]',
    dependent_vowel   = u'[\u09be-\u09cc\u09d7]',
    dependent_sign    = u'[\u0981-\u0983\u09cd]',
    virama            = u'[\u09cd]'
)
bangla_word_pattern = re.compile(ur'''(?:
    {consonant}
    ({virama}{consonant})?
    ({virama}{consonant})?
    {dependent_vowel}?
    {dependent_sign}?
    |
    {independent_vowel}
    {dependent_sign}?
)+
```

The matching is now:

```
bangla_word_pattern.match(w)
```

This code not only corrects errors, but accounts for more characters and valid constructs than before.

I am happy to report that it is working as expected. As such, this code now serves as a **very basic** regular expression for validating the syntax of Bengali words.

There are several special rules / exceptions not implemented. I will be looking into those and adding them to this basic structure incrementally.

Many ''.format(**bangla_alphabet), re.VERBOSE)

The matching is now:

*xCodexBlockxPlacexHolderx*

This code not only corrects errors, but accounts for more characters and valid constructs than before.

I am happy to report that it is working as expected. As such, this code now serves as a **very basic** regular expression for validating the syntax of Bengali words.

There are several special rules / exceptions not implemented. I will be looking into those and adding them to this basic structure incrementally.

Comment: You can change the `(` in `({virama}{consonant})?` to `(?:` for performance.

Comment: Ah yes, I'll do that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string `কয়া` is made up of these characters:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> map(unicodedata.name, u'কয়া')
['BENGALI LETTER KA', 'BENGALI LETTER YA', 'BENGALI SIGN NUKTA', 'BENGALI VOWEL SIGN AA']
```

U+09BC BENGALI SIGN NUKTA is not matched by your regular expression.

Looking at the [Bengali code chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0980.pdf) it seems possible that you missed some other characters.

---

OK, to answer your updated question. You are making three mistakes:

1. Your strings in the `BanglaAlphabet` dictionary are lacking the `u` (Unicode) flag. This means that Unicode escape sequences like `\u0995` are not being translated into Unicode characters. You just get backslashes, letters, and digits.
2. In the `BanglaWordPattern` regular expression, there is a vertical bar `|` near the end, with nothing after it. That means the whole regular expression looks like `(stuff1|stuff2|stuff3|stuff4|)+`. So there are really *five* alternatives, the last one being empty. The empty regular expression matches anything, of course.
3. You are not actually looking at the result of your program to see what it actually matched. If you write `m = re.match(BanglaWordPattern, w[::-1]); print m.group(0)` you'll see that what actually matched was the empty string.

I think the following are also mistakes, but you haven't explained what you are trying to do, so I'm not so confident:

1. You are doing the match backwards, which is unnecessary. It would be simpler and easier to understand if you turned your patterns round and matched forwards.
2. You are using capturing parentheses in your regular expressions. If you don't need the results, use non-capturing parentheses `(?:...)` instead.
3. The inner sets of parentheses are unnecessary anyway.
4. You are not anchoring the end of your regular expression at a word boundary or the end of the string.

I would write something like this:

```
import re

bangla_categories = dict(
    consonant         = u'[\u0995-\u09B9\u09CE\u09DC-\u09DF]',
    independent_vowel = u'[\u0985-\u0994]',
    dependent_vowel   = u'[\u09BE-\u09CC\u09D7]',
    nukta             = u'[\u09BC]',
)

bangla_word_re = re.compile(ur"""(?:
    {consonant}{nukta}{dependent_vowel} |
    {consonant}{dependent_vowel} |
    {independent_vowel} |
    {consonant}
)+(?:\b|$)""".format(**bangla_categories), re.VERBOSE)
```

But I would also look at the other Bangla signs in the code charts that you've omitted. What about U+0981 BENGALI SIGN CANDRABINDU and U+0982 BENGALI SIGN ANUSVARA (which nasalise vowels)? What about U+09CD BENGALI SIGN VIRAMA (which cancels a vowel)? And so on.

Comment: I don't know why the nukta character is there. The code chart says it's for 'extending the alphabet to new letters'. The problem is: when I changed {DependantVowel}{Consonant} to {DependantVowel}{Nukta}{Consonant}, EVERYTHING is matching the regex - even invalid words!

Comment: [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nukta) that Nukta "is used to represent sounds from other languages by being applied to an existing character".

Comment: I have updated my original post to reflect the present situation. Thanks.

Comment: I've added a large section (marked 'EDIT') to my original post. Take a look at it, and thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with what you've got:

- Your regular expressions end up including the literal `\u0995` etc. in them, because they're not Unicode strings; you need to include the actual Unicode character.
- You want `$` at the end of the regular expression so that it will only be matching the whole string.
- You had an empty string in your group as valid (by ending the first group with a pipe, leaving an empty option). This, in combination with the lack of a `$` symbol, meant that it wouldn't work.
- It's not complete (as observed by Gareth).

Also be aware that you can also do `bengali_word_pattern.match(s)` instead of `re.match(bengali_word_pattern, s)` once you've got a compiled regular expression object.

```
bengali_alphabet = {
    'consonant': u'[\u0995-\u09B9\u09CE\u09DC-\u09DF]',
    'independent_vowel': u'[\u0985-\u0994]',
    'dependent_vowel': u'[\u09BE-\u09CC\u09D7]',
    'nukta': u'\u09BC'
}

bengali_word_pattern = ur'''^(?:
    (?:{dependent_vowel}{nukta}{consonant}) |
    (?:{dependent_vowel}{consonant}) |
    {independent_vowel} |
    {consonant}
)+$'''.format(**bengali_alphabet)
bengali_word_pattern = re.compile(bengali_word_pattern, re.VERBOSE)
```

Now,

```
>>> bengali_word_pattern.match(u'বাংলা'[::-1])
```

This one doesn't work because of the "ং" character, U+0982; it's not in any of your ranges. Not sure what category that bit falls into off-hand; If we just take out the offending character it works. (Google Translate tells me that the resulting word could be translated "bracelet"—I don't know, I'd need to ask my sister; approximately all I can truthfully say is আমি বাংলা বলতে পারি না. Almost all I know is convenient everyday phrases like মুরগি চোর. And the first word of that contains a vowel missed thus far, too. Anyway, that's beside the point.)

```
>>> bengali_word_pattern.match(u'বালা')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f00f5bf9620>
```

It works on the "chicken thief" phrase, too.

```
>>> [bengali_word_pattern.match(w[::-1]) for w in u'মুরগি চোর'.split()]
[<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f00f5bf9620>, <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f00f5bf97e8>]
```

And it doesn't give a match for those two examples of incomplete words:

```
>>> bengali_word_pattern.match(u'োগাড়'[::-1])
>>> bengali_word_pattern.match(u'িদগ'[::-1])
```

I will also at this point admit myself puzzled as to why you are parsing the strings backwards; I would have thought it would make sense for it to be done forwards (this regular expression works correctly, then you don't need to use `[::-1]`):

```
^(?:
    {consonant}
    (?:
        {nukta}?
        {dependent_vowel}
    )?
    |
    {independent_vowel}
)+$
```

At each conjunct/letter, get either an independent vowel or a consonant possibly followed by a dependent vowel, with a nukta possibly between them.

Other alterations that I have made:

- Variable/item naming, to fit in with standard Python coding style;
- Replaced `(...)` (matching group) with `(?:...)` (non-matching group) for performance (see docs);
- Corrected the spelling of "dependent";
- Changed "bangla" to "bengali" as in English it is Bengali; I prefer when speaking English to use the standard English name for a language rather than the native language pronunciation, Anglicised if necessary—e.g. French rather than *le français*. On the other hand, I do realise that Bengali is regularly called Bangla by English speakers.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for that stunningly detailed answer. I'm now trying out all your suggestions, and I'll comment again in about 30 mins. Btw... convenient everyday phrases like মুরগি চোর??? You are aware that this means 'chicken thief'? :P

Comment: Yep, I know. ('It works on the "chicken thief" phrase, too.')

Comment: I've added a large section (marked 'EDIT') to my original post. Take a look at it, and thanks a million!